# SQL Alchemy return type

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am querying the table using `session.query().filter`. I get an output like:
`(u'1234')`. But when I try to translate this using `str.translate(None, '5)`, it throws an error

```
KeyedTuple' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Result is a object type. You could stored data to string variable to do translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a tuple with one element. You have to retrieve this one element first before using `result_string.translate` on it.

If you save the return of your `session.query().filter` inside a variable `result` do

```
if result: # Check that result is not empty
    result[0].translate(...)
```