# Why is tuple being returned?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following:

```
tableNumber = session.query(TABLE.TABLESNUMBER).filter_by(TABLESID=self.TABLESID).first()         
return str(tableNumber)
```

This is my `TABLE` class:

```
class TABLE(Base):

    ....   

    TABLESID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    TABLESNUMBER = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    ...
```

This is the output I  am receiving:

```
(1L,)
```

In my `mySQL database`, all both values above are represented as `ints`.

I would just like `1` to be returned.

Comment: could you cast the value? int(answer[0])

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Alchemy return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722402/sql-alchemy-return-type)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`query().first()` returns the first row. That's why a tuple is being returned. The query does not care that in the first row there is only 1 value, resulting in a tuple of length 1.

If you're sure the query will return only 1 scalar value, you can use [`scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html?highlight=scalar#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar) instead of `first()`. Please read up the linked documentation.

edit: To get the first value in the first returned tuple, when the query may return multiple rows, you can either add `order_by(...).limit(1)` to the query and then use `scalar()`, or get the first row and and then explicitly convert the tuple to an int.

Answer (score 2):

first() and all() return 'tuple'

So, 
`session.query(TABLE.TABLESNUMBER).filter_by(TABLESID=self.TABLESID).first()`
returns its tuple including 'TABLESNUMBER'

If you want exactly one value (TABLESNUMBER)

You can use it.
`session.query(TABLE.TABLESNUMBER).filter_by(TABLESID=self.TABLESID).first().TABLESNUMBER`